# Can't concat the output of command with string in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to redirect the output of command `wmic baseboard get serialnumber` with this string `HOST_MAC` in a file called `execution.txt`.

Here's my batch file:

```
@echo off

::REM Get the serial number using WMIC
 
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`wmic baseboard get serialnumber`) DO (
SET var=%%F
)
 
::REM Concatenate the serial number with the string "HOST_MAC"
set "host_mac=HOST_MAC=%var%"

::REM Save the result to a file
echo %host_mac% > "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\execution.txt"

pause
```

execution.txt file must looks like this:

```
HOST_MAC="OUTPUT_OF_COMMAND"
```

But what i get is `HOST_MAC=` and command don't redirect the output as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that I was facing is that the `wmic` command produces output with trailing whitespace, which affects the concatenation process.

And I solved this issue by changed:

1. In the `FOR /F` loop, we specify `tokens=2 delims==~` to extract the value after the equals sign `(=)` in the output of the `wmic` command. This eliminates any leading whitespace.
2. The `set` command now includes double quotes around `%var%`. This ensures that any whitespace in the variable is preserved and does not interfere with the concatenation.

Here's the script after applying my changes:

```
@echo off

:: Get the serial number using WMIC
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%F IN ('wmic baseboard get serialnumber /value') DO (
    SET "var=%%F"
)

:: Concatenate the serial number with the string "HOST_MAC"
set "host_mac=HOST_MAC="%var%""

:: Save the result to a file
echo %host_mac% > "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\execution.txt"

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

`"tokens=* USEBACKQ"` causes `CR LF` control characters that are not seen in the output.
Also you need a single number.

So I suggest you this code:

```
@echo off

::REM Get the serial number using WMIC
 
FOR /F %%F IN ('wmic baseboard get serialnumber ^| findstr /r "[0-9]"') DO (
SET var=%%F
)
 
::REM Concatenate the serial number with the string "HOST_MAC"
set "host_mac=HOST_MAC="%var%""

::REM Save the result to a file
echo %host_mac% > "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\execution.txt"

pause
```

Output:

```
HOST_MAC="921891283912839"
```

Answer (score 1):

To perform define a variable from your WMIC command, then at some point afterwards output its value to a text file, I'd offer this method instead:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Rem Undefine any potential pre-existing variable named host_mac.
Set "host_mac="

Rem Try to define host_mac with the SerialNumber property of Win32_BaseBoard.
For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe BaseBoard Get Serialnumber /Format:MOF 2^>NUL')Do Set "host_mac=HOST_MAC="%%G""

Rem Send the value string of the host_mac variable to a stdOut location, if it is defined.
If Defined host_mac (1>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\execution.txt" Echo %host_mac%)

EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```

Another, and quicker way, might be to use your original structure, but to utilise Windows Script Host via `cscript.exe` instead of `WMIC.exe`. *(This will be useful for those who have upgraded to versions of Windows 11+ which no longer has WMIC.exe too)*.

```bash
<!-- ::Script Language="Batch"
    @Echo Off
    SetLocal EnableExtensions

    Rem Undefine any potential pre-existing variable named host_mac.
    Set "host_mac="

    Rem Try to define host_mac using the SerialNumber property of Win32_BaseBoard.
    For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf"')Do Set "host_mac=%%G"

    Rem Send the value string of the host_mac variable to a stdOut location, if it is defined.
    If Defined host_mac (1>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\execution.txt" Echo %host_mac%)

    Pause
    EndLocal
    Exit /B
-->
<Job>
    <Script Language="VBScript">
        Set ColItems = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\Root\CIMv2").ExecQuery("Select SerialNumber From Win32_BaseBoard")
        For Each ObjItem In ColItems
            WScript.Echo "HOST_MAC=" & Chr(34) & ObjItem.SerialNumber & Chr(34)
        Next
    </Script>
</Job>
```

Alternatively, although not as speedy, if you just wanted the output directly inside the file, you may be able to just get away with this single line batch file, which uses `powershell.exe`:

```bash
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "Write-Host \"HOST_MAC=`\"$($(gcim Win32_BaseBoard).SerialNumber)`\"\"" 1>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\execution.txt"
```